# How to train a Keras model without freezing a GUI?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, kivy

I'm trying to create a GUI using kivy framework for creating a Keras model.
The problem is when I try to train a model GUI freezes.

According to the link (https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Working-with-Python-threads-inside-a-Kivy-application), I tried to fix this problem using threads. But the code I wrote doesn't work as expected. Any suggestions would be appreciated

The .kv file is the same as on the link and here is my python code:

```py
import threading
import time

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train.astype('float32'), x_test.astype('float32')
x_train, x_test = x_train.reshape(60000,28,28,1) / 255.0, x_test.reshape(10000,28,28,1) / 255.0
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

model = Sequential([
                Flatten(input_shape=input_shape),
            Dense(10, activation='softmax')
        ])

class UpdateProgressBar(Callback):
    epoch = 0
    def __init__(self, th):
        self.th = th

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.epoch = epoch
        self.th.update_label_text(str(epoch))

class RootWidget(GridLayout):

    stop = threading.Event()

    def start_second_thread(self, l_text):
        threading.Thread(target=self.second_thread, args=(l_text,),daemon = True).start()

    def second_thread(self, label_text):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.start_test, 0)

        self.stop_test()
        # Start a new thread with an infinite loop and stop the current one.
        threading.Thread(target=self.infinite_loop).start()

    def start_test(self, *args):
        global model
        model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size = 64, epochs=5, verbose=1,callbacks =[UpdateProgressBar(self)])

    @mainthread
    def update_label_text(self, new_text):
        self.lab_2.text = new_text

    @mainthread
    def stop_test(self):
        self.lab_1.text = ('Second thread exited, a new thread has started. '
                           'Close the app to exit the new thread and stop '
                           'the main process.')

        self.lab_2.text = str(int(self.lab_2.text) + 1)

    def infinite_loop(self):
        iteration = 0
        while True:
            if self.stop.is_set():
                # Stop running this thread so the main Python process can exit.
                return
            iteration += 1
            print('Infinite loop, iteration {}.'.format(iteration))
            time.sleep(1)

buildKV = Builder.load_file("thread.kv")

class ThreadedApp(App):
    def on_stop(self):
        self.root.stop.set()
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ThreadedApp().run()
```

Comment: how it works ? Do you get error message or what ?

Comment: It works without errors, but while the model is training, GUI is frozen. If I click on it a few times, it says "Not Responding". When training is finished, all is returned to normal.

Comment: I don't know why you use Clock to start model. It may blocks your code. Clock starts your model and wait for its end. You should start model directly in this thread without Clock or use Clock to start thread with model, not directly model.

Comment: If I don't use Clock for running start_test function it throws an exception in thread Thread-6: ValueError: Tensor("loss/dense_loss/Const:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("dense/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32).

In the case where the thread is created using Clock it throws exception too: ValueError: callback must be a callable, got None in kivy._clock.CyClockBase.schedule_once

So obviously the function should be scheduled with Clock. :/

Comment: Clock needs name of function without `()` - it can be function which will create thread and start it. You can't put function with `()` because it will first run function and next get its return value (which as default can be `None`) and then use this value in Clock as name of function. So you get `result = Thread().start()`. `Clock(target=result)`.Maybe if you put `start` without `()` then it will work `Clock(targe=Thread(...).start)`

Comment: if you get error with graph size then maybe there is some problem with this network, not with thread.

Comment: Oh wait, actually I forgot to delete parentheses in the second case, and It doesn't throw an exception, but it seems like it doesn't even create a new thread. Nothing's happening after pressing the button.

Comment: I think that there is no problem with the network because I can run it without any errors without creating a thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas) was right, there was no need for using Clock scheduling.
The problem was the TensorFlow graph. The graph should be previously saved as a global, and thread function should look like:

```py
def second_thread(self, ):
        with graph.as_default():
            model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                        loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                        metrics=['accuracy'])
            model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                        batch_size = 60,
                        epochs=5,
                        verbose=1,
                        callbacks =[UpdateProgressBar(self)])
        self.stop_test()
        threading.Thread(target=self.infinite_loop).start()
```

Solution is found on the following link: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2397#issuecomment-254919212